# SQL Server Check String for Spaces, Special Characters, and Charcters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a report that produces a list of values that should all be numbers but are currently stored as a varchar. In my export I am casting the varchar character as an Int but when some one incorrectly enters a char or a special character the report fails because is cannot convert to an INT

```
Current List
557780
558871
5588a6
5588 7
```

What I need is something that will swap out those values that contain spaces or characters for an error int like 99999999 so the end result would be

```
557780
558871
99999999
99999999
```

I know I can do this by using something like this

```
CASE WHEN SomeNum LIKE '%_%' THEN 99999999 ELSE SomeNum
     WHEN SomeNum LIKE '%a%' THEN 99999999 ELSE SomeNum END
```

But is there a better way then to compare to every letter and special charterer individually?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this on SQL 2012+:

```
SELECT COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(INT, SomeNum), 99999999) AS Value
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use do it with pattern

```
case when SomeNum NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN 99999999 ELSE cast(SomeNum as int) END
```

Comment: I tried this but I still get the same error Conversion Failed

Comment: @ScholarYoshi, you need to do cast in else  cast(someNum as int)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ISNUMERIC` if you are in [SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) or later. Note this will match money and decimals etc. If you are just looking for integer then you need to regex. See radar's answer.

Their example is this for completeness:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT City, PostalCode
FROM Person.Address 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(PostalCode)<> 1;
GO
```

If you are pre SQL Server 2008 you could use Radar's answer with a regex